# Trouble with alignment while using a jQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, alignment, slideshow

I'm using this [jQuery Slideshow](http://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2011/06/17/simple-jquery-slideshow-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-jquery-cycle) code and it pretty much works fine except that my images are different widths and they're automatically being aligned to the left of the slideshow within the arrows, rather than in the centre.

This is fine for the images that are the same width as the slideshow container, however those that are narrower are off center, and adding a simple div align doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the images in `div's` with the same size as the slideshow container and apply `text-align: center` to the `div's`.

Comment: Could you possibly show an example please? I'm afraid I'm pretty unfamiliar with this coding.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/E9q9g/ I wrapped div's around the slider images, and added `text-align: center` to the div's.